# How To Draw This Pattern

Tags: python, string, for-loop, nested-loops

**Details Of Problem**

I am stuck in this. How should I approach this when I have to accept a string from the user and form the following pattern:

[image]

**What I Tried**

I am able to form this pattern but in bottom line two R are coming which is not needed.

```
S=input("Enter a String! ")
for i in range(len(S)):
  print(" "*i,end="")
  print(S[i])
```

```
S=input("Enter a String! ")
for i in range(len(S)):
  print(" "*i,end="")
  print(S[i],end="")
  print(" "*2*(len(S)-(i+1)),end="")
  print(S[i])
```

The R Shouldn't come two times.

Comment: Simply reduce the range of your for loop, remove a space from between the letters in the for loop, and print the last line after the loop.

Comment: Great, Thanks! For Your Efforts